# Remove Array Value By index in jquery

Tags: jquery

Array:

```
var arr = {'abc','def','ghi'};
```

I want to remove above array value 'def' by using index.

Comment: is it ok to copy it into new array without your index

Comment: The OP has confused the syntax of creating an object with creating an array. The correct syntax for an array would be: `var arr = [ "abc", "def", "ghi" ];`

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Use [the splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
ArrayName.splice(indexValueOfArray,1);
```

This removes `1` item from the array starting at `indexValueOfArray`.

Comment: Useful to know that `.splice` also returns an array of the object(s) removed

Answer (score 29):

Your example code is wrong and will throw a SyntaxError. You seem to have confused the syntax of creating an object [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) with creating an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

The correct syntax would be: `var arr = [ "abc", "def", "ghi" ];`

To remove an item from the array, based on its value, use the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method:

```
arr.splice(arr.indexOf("def"), 1);
```

To remove it by index, just refer directly to it:

```
arr.splice(1, 1);
```

Comment: This one is more correct than the accepted answer.. +1 for pointing out that OP didn't use `array` "braces" (`[]`), and for `object` the syntax is invalid - meaning invalid in either case... just as an pointer, it would be nice to include `delete` in the answer to show how to delete from an `object`.

Answer (score 13):

Your syntax is incorrect, you should either specify a hash:

```
hash = {abc: true, def: true, ghi: true};
```

Or an array:

```
arr = ['abc','def','ghi'];
```

You can effectively remove an item from a hash by simply setting it to null:

```
hash['def'] = null;
hash.def = null;
```

Or removing it entirely:

```
delete hash.def;
```

To remove an item from an array you have to iterate through each item and find the one you want (there may be duplicates). You could use array searching and splicing methods:

```
arr.splice(arr.indexOf("def"), 1);
```

This finds the first index of "def" and then removes it from the array with splice.
However I would recommend .filter() because it gives you more control:

```
arr.filter(function(item) { return item !== 'def'; });
```

This will create a new array with only elements that are not 'def'.

It is important to note that arr.filter() will return a new array, while arr.splice will modify the original array and return the removed elements. These can both be useful, depending on what you want to do with the items.

Comment: Setting an attribute to `null` doesn't remove it. You will need to use `delete` for that.

Comment: Already updated :) for the most part you don't need to use delete though.

Comment: You use `delete` when you want to remove an attribute. Setting it to `null` or `undefined` is bad practice since that would use up more memory then necessary.

Comment: Actually, using `delete` can be considered bad practice because it takes vastly longer than setting to `null` or `undefined`.

However, both points are invalid, because the memory and time we're talking about it completely negligible in most cases.

Comment: `typeof null != "undefined"` so no point of suggesting it as a possible option, only `delete` is the correct way!

Comment: It depends entirely what you want to do. If your check for presence in the object is simply `if (object[key])` then it makes no difference what kind of falsey value you are using. 

And using `undefined` has the same result as `delete` all cases except when enumerating/counting the properties.

Answer (score 4):

1. Find the element in array and get its position
2. Remove using the position

```js
var array = new Array();
  
array.push('123');
array.push('456');
array.push('789');
                 
var _searchedIndex = $.inArray('456',array);
alert(_searchedIndex );
if(_searchedIndex >= 0){
  array.splice(_searchedIndex,1);
  alert(array );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

- inArray() - helps you to find the position.
- splice() - helps you to remove the element in that position.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete arr[1]
```

Try this out, it should work if you have an array like var `arr =["","",""]`

Comment: This is bad practice. `delete` will not remove the item from the array, but set it to `undefined`.

Comment: seeing that it is the alphabet he might want to put something back in there

Comment: That's purely based on the assumption that those strings are the actual values and not placeholders, but a nice save nonetheless :)