# Remove an element from an associative array by the value of the index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following associative array in jQuery:

```
var main_new_smarket_image_tags_list = {
    1: "value1",
    4: "value4",
    2: "value2",
    8: "value8"
};
```

And I want to delete elements according to the value of the index. For example, delete the element with the index `2`. Then it would look like this:

```
main_new_smarket_image_tags_list = {
    1: "value1",
    4: "value4",
    8: "value8"
};
```

Comment: I do not see any jQuery here...? `delete main_new_smarket_image_tags_list[2]`

Comment: Associative Array is a term used in PHP (among other languages) in JavaScript this is simply an `object`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you very much! It's just what I needed.

Comment: Just a technical side note, the keys in an object in JS are strings. As you've done here, you can declare them as number primitives, and they would automatically be coerced to strings. (You can see that they are strings by using `Object.keys`: `Object.keys({1:0, 2:0});`, returns an array of strings containing numbers.) Likewise doing `delete someObj[2]` coerces the `2` to a string, `'2'`, so it is effectively doing `delete someObj['2']`. There is nothing wrong with doing this, using a string instead of a number is an unnecessary micro-optimization, but it is just something to be aware of.

Comment: @amenthes There are associative arrays in JavaScript 
`var a = {}; a['key'] = 1; Array.isArray(a);`
false
`var a = []; a['key'] = 1; Array.isArray(a);`
true
`typeof` will return in both cases 'Object' but as you see `isArray` won't do the same. First case defines an Object, the second an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

I'm amending my answer as I got confused by your question and the actual code. Your question concerned arrays but your code is an object.

Since you're working with an object you need to get the key for the value you want to remove then call `delete object[key]`.

Example

```js
var main_new_smarket_image_tags_list = {
   1: "value1",
   4: "value4",
   2: "value2",
   8: "value8"
};

var key = 2;

delete main_new_smarket_image_tags_list[key];
//{"1": "value1", "4": "value4", "8": "value8"}
console.log(main_new_smarket_image_tags_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/eKGXVr

```
var main_new_smarket_image_tags_list = {
    1: "value1",
    4: "value4",
    2: "value2",
    8: "value8"
};
var removeindex = 2;
var newcontent = {};
$.each(main_new_smarket_image_tags_list, function(i,v){
  if(i != removeindex){
    newcontent[i] = v; 
  }
})
console.log(newcontent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

ArrayName.splice(indexValueOfArray,1);

Also click below.

[Remove Array Value By index in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724363/remove-array-value-by-index-in-jquery)

Comment: The question is not about removing an item from an array, it is about removing an item from an object. In JS objects act in a similar way to [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)s, also known as dictionaries, in other languages; which is probably why the OP called it an associative array in the question, but it is in fact an object.

Answer (score -1):

You can go over the whole object and `delete` the key where the value matches:

```
var main_new_smarket_image_tags_list = {
    1: "value1",
    4: "value4",
    2: "value2",
    8: "value8"
};

var value_to_delete = "value2"; // <-- could come from anywhere.

for (var key in main_new_smarket_image_tags_list) {  // <-- loops over all items
    if (main_new_smarket_image_tags_list[key] === value_to_delete) { // <- checks for the value
        delete main_new_smarket_image_tags_list[key];  // <-- this deletes they key (along with the value)
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not `delete the element with the index 2`. That deletes the element with the *value* `value2`.