# why my array is not deleting proper records

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this example I am trying to delete records based on my index value, but why my records are not deleted properly?
I have added screen shot in which I am trying to delete 21.png and coo.png But after removing it again, I get 2a.png instead of cat.png

```
$scope.remove = function (abc) {
    var newDataList = [];
    $scope.selectedAll = false;
    var newval;
    for (var i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
        if (abc[i].selected == true) {
            var _filedata = $scope.Files.indexOf(abc[i])
            $scope.Files.splice(_filedata, 1)           
        } 
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use splice method, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724363/remove-array-value-by-index-in-jquery) might help.

Answer (score 2):

Try iterating your array in inverse direction:

```
for (var i = abc.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (abc[i].selected == true) {
    var _filedata = $scope.Files.indexOf(abc[i])
    $scope.Files.splice(_filedata, 1)
  }
}
```

When you iterate in ascending order and you modify the array via `splice` but your for loop does not know about it and `i` variable carries index of the original array (while after calling `splice`, indexes has changed).

Comment: Yes, it's perfect answer.